# How to install a different language for Language Plural Rules?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

How to install a different language for Language Plural Rules?
http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

I need used russian ruls.

```
return array(
    'view_title' => array(
        'one' => 'просмотр',
        'few' => 'просмотра',
        'many' => 'просмотров',
        'other' => 'просмотров2',
    ),

echo ___('view_title', $post->view_count, array(':count' => $post->view_count));
```

few and many not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Kohana 3.x does not support plural in the core system.  You need to use some other method.

Someone wrote a replacement module that does suppport plural.

- http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/6833/i18n-plurals-module
- https://github.com/czukowski/I18n_Plural

Using that module, you will be able to use plural for russian rules the way you want.

See the instructions for installation and usage here:

- https://github.com/czukowski/I18n_Plural/blob/3.1/master/README.md

Or, you can always use Zend Framework's I18n modules Zend_Translate which does support plural:

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.plurals.html

Comment: "Choosing correct translation option when translating plural amount of any term, based on CLDR Language Plural Rules" - why??? I use i18n_pliral